# How to derive conclusions from these profiler results

Tags: java, garbage-collection, profiling, heap-memory

I am running a mule 2.2.1 stand alone server and profiling it using yourkit. I am trying to analyze the the profilers output and would appreciate if some one could help in reading the results.

About 99% of the heap space is consumed by String and char[] is this normal ?, Should i be looking into this ?

The PS Old Gen consumes 2.7 GB of the total 3.4 GB heap space used. How should i interpret this ? It never

In the GC section it tells me that it spent 20% of its time in GC however i do not see any minor or major collections, How should i read this ?

[image: Memory consumption]

[image: GC behavior]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`About 99% of the heap space is consumed by String and char[] is this normal ?`

You should open the references screen and check who is holding these `Strings` and `char[]`. **If is some of your application classes, its definitely abnormal.** In that case, revisit your code and make sure your object references are getting freed up for garbage collection.

`The PS Old Gen consumes 2.7 GB of the total 3.4 GB heap space used.`

This much heap spaces used doesn't sound right upfront. If you have high volume application and caching huge data by design then it might be OK. If not, your object references should give you the clear picture of `why`. Once you get to know the cause(unwanted object references), then clear them up.

**Possible Memory Leak:**

In the non memory leak screen, Its not very clear but looks like graph is eventually(overall) going up. Please review your data for little longer duration ignoring the spikes and make sure it's not going up. If it is going up, then there is possibly some memory leaks in your application code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "You should open the references screen and check who is holding these" I could not find this tab. How could i trace the references to these strings ?  No the application by itself does not cache much data. "In the non memory leak screen" did u mean non heap tab ? Any ideas on the GC behavior ?

Comment: Are you referring to something like "Paths from GC roots" from http://www.yourkit.com/docs/11/help/paths.jsp. From your experience could this kind of behavior cause a 2-3 second pause in the application ?

Comment: @Sudarshan: Yes. Check if your application classes are appearing in the path. High memory dependency and memory leaks do cause performance degradation in the application.

Comment: For the gc behaviour could out be that our troopers to gc but cannot because of strong references ?

Comment: @Sudarshan  It is possible but in small size. Also you can `force run the garbage collection` to ensure all free objects are release before your analysis.

Comment: "It is possible but in small size" -- I did not get this. In my above comment "troopers" should be "tries"